# Don't change cursor over TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, mouse-cursor

I am trying to make a TextBox look like a TextBlock to the user (it is in a treeview that I want to allow renaming in). I was able to do this by applying a style to set the border and background to transparent and the IsReadOnly property to true. My only problem is that the mouse cursor still changes from the pointer style to the editing (caret) style. Is there an easy way to disable this (preferably in xaml)?

Comment: What exactly is disturbing you? That when you hover over the textbox the cursor changes to caret? Or that when you click on the textbox the blinking caret appears?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, just set the TextBox's `Cursor` property to `Arrow`

```
<TextBox Cursor="Arrow" />
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was probably simple!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
TextBox.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can be set in XAML, but in code you should be able to change the [`Cursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor.aspx) property of the `TextBox`. Alternately, you should be able to have full control over the cursor if you create a control template to overwrite the `TextBox` in its entirety. Hopefully the former will do the trick.

**EDIT**

As an extension to the above, if you need to handle the mouse hovering over the `TextBox` to determine when to set the `Cursor` property, you can handle the `TextBox`'s [`MouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx) and [`MouseLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave.aspx) events.